# Trying to draw liquid on floor in 2d (Opengl directly write array of byte into stencil buffer)

Tags: opengl, libgdx, depth-buffer, stencil-buffer

Currently I'm making 2d game with java libgdx.
In my game I need to have multiple kinds of liquid to occupy floor of room. (something like splatoon but in 2d)
Each liquid need track of what entity it is in touch with and should be able to change where they occupy in runtime based on what players do.
So approach I took was, give number to each liquid and create array of byte with same size of room's width*height to fill liquid into.
It works well in its function but, I have some problem in graphic side.
I need to fill in area of liquid with texture for each liquid. but I'm kinda lost on how to do it.

From searching, closest thing I've achieved so far was to create texture from array of byte through pixmap.
Then use these textures as stencil buffer mask. It works fine for visual side, but it is extremely slow.

so my question is

1. Is there any better way to draw and check collision for dynamic changing objects in 2D than using array of byte?
2. If not, Is there any better way to 'fill in' only selected area from array of byte than stencil buffer?
3. If not, Is there more direct/faster way to use array of byte as stencil buffer mask?

Comment: Probably not. It shouldn't be extremely slow. Minecraft's animated textures, for example, are images that get updated every single frame. Perhaps it's a libgdx issue?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I think it is too. I assume pixmap class converting array of byte into texture runtime is causing slowness. So, I want opengl to directly use array of byte as stencil mask without libgdx library or through pixmap class. But don't know how to directly use array of byte as stencil buffer mask in opengl.

Comment: It could be slowness specifically related to how the data goes into the stencil buffer. But you don't actually need the stencil buffer, do you? Maybe try uploading it as a texture (you can use format GL_STENCIL_INDEX8 or GL_R8UI) and writing a shader that draws the pixels based on this texture?

Comment: @user253751 I'm not familiar with opengl. So I'm kind of confused about what you are exactly suggesting. Is this mean rather than using stencil buffer create GL_STENCIL_INDEX8 texture with byte array and then, pass both stencil texture and image texture into fragment shader to check if the pixel should be drawn?

Comment: that's what I mean. How do you get the byte array into the stencil buffer using a pixmap?

Comment: @user253751 Those part was handled through libgdx library so I'm kinda unsure. Tried reading source code but as some of method are native its hard for me to completely follow. So is it right to understand as opengl accept drawing as vertices there is no direct way of byte array into stencil so, create texture with something like glTexImage2D and use that texture to check what pixel will be drawn. right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would try. I wondered if libgdx was using glDrawPixels to update the stencil buffer, which is generally known to be very slow.

Comment: @user253751 Ok, thank you very much for clearing up what i was confused about! will try it and see if it works!

Comment: I know OpenGL, but I don't know libgdx.

Comment: Pixmap manipulation that you upload to the GPU on every frame is too slow. This kind of thing needs to be done in the shader. You can also modify a texture in real-time fast enough if it's attached to a FrameBuffer that you're rendering to. Would need a lot more detail to understand the problem and be able to suggest a strategy.